# how to know which device was open

Tags: shell, devices

is there any shell command, can let me know, current open device or device already in operation.

For example, I use minicom to open a device `/dev/ttyUSB0` or `/dev/ttyS0`, after I use program open this device, how can I check it under shell it already open? I tried `dmesg` but seems doesn't work for me

Comment: [`lsof(8)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/lsof.8), perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think lsof is the tool that should be used for.  It will list all the files that are being used by a process.

May be fuser can also be used if you want do not know the process id.

Answer (score 2):

`lsof <your devices>` to show the processes that use your device.
or `strace -p pid` to trace a process that you know is supposed to use your device.

Answer (score 1):

### Block devices

The examples given in the question are *not* block devices, but the question is asked generically, so if yours *is* a block device, use:

```
badblocks -n -c1 /dev/device-name 0 0
```

This will try to do a non-destructive re-write of the first 1024 bytes of the device

If it's in use, you'll see:

> ```
> /dev/device-name is apparently in use by the system; it's not safe to run badblocks!
> ```